# Having Issues with upgrading to Tensorflow 1.2 from Tensorflow 0.12

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am trying to learn how to use tensorflow however, I am having trouble actually running the latest version of tensorflow-gpu on windows 10 using python 3.5.2

I am able to install and run tensorflow-gpu version .12 and it connects correctly to the 5 libraries of cuda.

I looked at stack exchange to find a solution for my issue and one did came up however it seems as though it doesn't work. I already tried reinstalling protobuf but that didn't work.

Here's the error I am getting (scroll down to the last line of the error):

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3038, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3022, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3066, in _initialize_master_working_set
    for dist in working_set
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3066, in <genexpr>
    for dist in working_set
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2597, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2165, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2100, in _handle_ns
    loader.load_module(packageName)
  File "C:\Users\Gal's\Desktop\stock_learning\google.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\examples\tutorials\mnist\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\examples\tutorials\mnist\input_data.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import read_data_sets
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import bayesflow
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\bayesflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.bayesflow.python.ops import entropy
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\bayesflow\python\ops\entropy.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.bayesflow.python.ops.entropy_impl import *
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\bayesflow\python\ops\entropy_impl.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.bayesflow.python.ops import variational_inference
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\bayesflow\python\ops\variational_inference.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.bayesflow.python.ops.variational_inference_impl import *
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\bayesflow\python\ops\variational_inference_impl.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.bayesflow.python.ops import stochastic_graph_impl as sg
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\bayesflow\python\ops\stochastic_graph_impl.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.bayesflow.python.ops import stochastic_tensor_impl
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\bayesflow\python\ops\stochastic_tensor_impl.py", line 50, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.bayesflow.python.ops import stochastic_gradient_estimators as sge
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\bayesflow\python\ops\stochastic_gradient_estimators.py", line 65, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.training import training
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\training.py", line 118, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.training.sync_replicas_optimizer import SyncReplicasOptimizer
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\sync_replicas_optimizer.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.training import queue_runner
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\queue_runner.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.training.queue_runner_impl import *
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\queue_runner_impl.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.client import session
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\Pycharm\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.5\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "F:\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\protobuf\config_pb2.py", line 30, in <module>
    dependencies=[tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_cost__graph__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_graph__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_step__stats__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,tensorflow_dot_core_dot_protobuf_dot_debug__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,tensorflow_dot_core_dot_protobuf_dot_cluster__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,tensorflow_dot_core_dot_protobuf_dot_rewriter__config__pb2.DESCRIPTOR,])
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2' has no attribute 'DESCRIPTOR'
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go all out and delete any remaining tensorflow files and python and just completely reinstall everything. Worked like a charm!